# RoR form_for: Hidden field isn't being included within the object parameter and therefore doesn't work.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-for

I'm using a form to add an entry, and I need to send the id of the current user along with the entry parameters. Here is my form code:

```
<% form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id  %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :note %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :note %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that user_id is being saved as null. I noticed in the console output below that user_id is present, but it isn't actually located ***within*** the entry object parameters. How can I fix this? Thanks for reading.

```
Processing EntriesController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-07-09 19:57:55) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "action"=>"create", "user_id"=>"3", "entry"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2010", "date(2i)"=>"7", "date(3i)"=>"9", "note"=>"bb"}, "controller"=>"entries"}
  Entry Create (0.4ms)   INSERT INTO "entries" ("entry_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "date", "user_id", "note") VALUES(NULL, '2010-07-09 09:57:55', '2010-07-09 09:57:55', '2010-07-09', NULL, 'bb')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/entries/7
Completed in 24ms (DB: 0) | 302 Found [http://localhost/entries]
```

Answer (score 20):

The other answers are written for Rails 2.  The Rails 3 adaptation of Salil's answer uses this format:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the most highly voted one is now out of date.

Answer (score 16):

USE

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id  %>
```

INSTEAD OF

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id  %>
```

Explaination:- 
    In controller probably you doing something like follwing

```
@entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
@entry.save  #But there is no params[:entry][:user_id] so null is getting saved
```

So you have to one of the following (othere than one i mention above)

```
@entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
@entry.user_id= params[:user_id]
@entry.save
```

or

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'entry[user_id]', current_user.id  %>
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I just wanted to update your answer as it doesn't seem to work for Rails 3.0.7.  I was getting an error relating to merge, so I had to google a few places to find this:
`<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>`

Comment: @EricHu - you should submit your comment as an answer, every time I need to do this I end up referring to your comment!

Answer (score 7):

For Rails 4 use:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

include the hidden field with your form builder object 'f'

> f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id